# Disable upgrading of single-word addresses in Safari

Tags: safari

When entering a single word domain (ie. `example/`, `http://example/` or `http://example:8080`), in Safari on macOS, Safari will *sometimes* change it to http://www.example.com. I suspect this is a feature designed to help inapt users, but it kicks in at unwanted times, and I don't want this feature!

It seems like this is dependent on some kind of caching (possibly DNS), so that if Safari first decides to change it, it will keep changing it no matter how many times I type it correctly. But after maybe a few hours, it will do as I expect.

How do I disable this pesky "smart URL conversion" feature?

Comment: A localhost address?  `localhost` is a very specific thing.  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

Here, you are actually searching for a word in your default search engine and go to the first hit. You can either type `http://` before your host name or if you have control over that host name, try to change it to `example.local` or similar which contains a dot (`.`).

Also, after the first use if `http://example` to visit that page (putting `http://` manually), next time you will be able to use the hostname without the hassle to put `http' first. Till you remove it from history.

Comment: Then I'd have to map `example.local` in `/etc/hosts` and have similar duplicate items for all local domains, which is undesired. I was hoping there was a `defaults` key I could change to make Safari (or macOS) stop doing this.

Comment: I tried to clarify manual usage, see the second paragraph in the answer.

Comment: Interesting, but it sounds annoying having to remember to do workarounds like this. But the main question is if Safari/macOS can be configured not to translate addresses to begin with.

Comment: Well you have to disable searching via address bar, but I am not sure that's possible. See [this].(https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74162/turn-off-address-bar-search)